# When i'm calling api, i am using below method please give the solution, i install Afnetwoking through COCOAPOD

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
-(void)resquestWithPost:(NSDictionary*)params Path:(NSString*)path completionAction:(CompletionBlock)completionBlock  error:(ErrorBlock)errorBlock
{
    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
        KAlertView(@"Alert", @"There IS NO internet connection");

    } else
    {
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        NSString *str_url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",KbaseURl,path];


        [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",KbaseURl,path] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSData *jsonData = [responseObject dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:true];
              completionBlock(jsonData);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            errorBlock(error);

        }];

    }
}
```

This is genrating error

> Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"
>   UserInfo=0x8abf470 {
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=.......NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=......NSUnderlyingError=0x8dafed0
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error
>   -1012.)" }

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
[securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
[securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
```

Comment: it's working. Can you tell me what u had done..  what is the purpose of adding setAllowInvalidCertificates

Comment: You were trying to authenticate in a server that doesn't have a valid certificate. So to do so we  set `YES` for property `allowInvalidCertificates` in  `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` object.

Comment: Vadeky: How to check if sever has valid certificate or not. for my knowledge it has valid certificate